# Set all links within DIV ID to return false

Tags: javascript

I have something like the following:

```
<div id="songs">
<ul>
<li> <a href="(a real link)">song 1</a></li>
<li> <a href="(a real link)">song 2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I want all links within the div#songs to be automatically set to return false with javascript (so that the link will open only if javascript is disabled); and I don't want to have to add `onclick="return false"` to every link.

I'm not at all strong with Javascript so any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

ETA that by this ^^ I meant that I won't know what you're talking about unless you lay out the whole code. Sorry about that and thanks again for your help.

Comment: Add an event with [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener), then prevent the default behavior with `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: And to complete elclanrs comment, use `document.querySelectorAll` to get the `a` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an event listener to all of the links like so:

```
var root = document.getElementById('songs'),
links = root.getElementsByTagName('a'),
doNothing = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
};

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; ++i) {
    links[i].addEventListener('click', doNothing, false);
}
```

This works for IE >= 9; for older versions, either use `attachEvent` instead of `addEventListener` or modify the `onclick` property, the latter being more universally understood.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Can you tell me why this only works for IE9+ and if there's a way to work around that?

Comment: @user2860129 Before IE9 you should use `attachEvent`.

Comment: @user2860129 Alternatively, use `links[i].onclick = doNothing;`

Comment: issues with older version of IE with getElementsByTagName and addEventListener

Comment: @CharlieAffumigato `getElementsByTagName` is pretty darn old ... which version are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are targeting modern browsers (ES5 compatible)

1) get all the links ("a" tags) inside the songs

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('songs a'),
function noop(e) { e.preventDefault() },
forEach=Array.prototype.forEach;
```

2.a) If you are just planning on disabling the click

```
forEach.call(links,function(theLink){theLink.onclick=noop});
```

2.b) If you intend to add other click event handlers then

```
forEach.call(links,function(theLink){theLink.addEventListener('click', noop, false);});
```